# replaceAll not working with PreSaveAction()

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have a one line of code that would not work inside the function PreSaveAction (for sharepoint list). 
It works outside the PreSaveAction function! any idea what is wrong with it?

```
MyVar.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "").trim().isEmpty();
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, my initial guess is that the MyVar is out of scope.

Comment: Not true. it is in the scope. it is defined inside the function

Comment: difficult to assess without the code.

Comment: I had: var MyVar  = document.getElementById("ctl00...."); which was regenerated with different id.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to easily get element by its internal name or field name?

Comment: Yes, in fact relying on the auto generated ct IDs isn't good for repeatability. By far the easiest way is to use jQuery and reference like $('input[title="MyColName"]').val()

Comment: thanks Paul, this field is multi choices; so would this work:
$('select[title="MyColName"]').val(); then: myval.options[myval.selectedIndex].text;

Comment: Sure, the selector is slightly different but the same approach works. $('select[title="MyColName"]') you'll need to dig into the element slightly differently too. Plenty of jQuery/SharePoint help about.

Comment: for those who are coming from Google this might help: this what worked for me: 
    'code' var e = $('select[title="IntenalFieldName"] option:selected').text(); 'code'